# Matching a generated string of random letters to an input

Tags: c#, python, performance, strings, validation

I made a program in Python and wanted it to be faster, so I wrote it on C# because it's compiled. To my surprise, the Python program is much faster. I guess there is something wrong with my C# code, but it is pretty simple and straightforward, so I don't know. They are structured about the same way.

**C#:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Diagnostics;

//This program generates a string of random lowercase letters and matches it to the user's input
//It does this until it gets a match
//It also displays the closest guess so far and the time it took to guess

namespace Monkey
{
    class Program
    {
        static string userinput()
        {
            //Takes user input, makes sure it is all lowercase letters, returns string
            string input;

            while(true)
            {
                input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[a-z]+$"))
                {
                    return input;
                }
            }
        }

        static string generate(int len)
        {
            //generates string of random letters, returns the random string
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            int letterInt;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                letterInt = rnd.Next(26);
                sb.Append(alpha[letterInt]);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        static int count(int len, string s, string g)
        {
            //returns number of letters that match user input
            int same = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                if(g[i] == s[i])
                {
                    same++;
                }
            }

            return same;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("They say if you lock a monkey in a room with a typewriter and enough time,");
            Console.WriteLine("the monkey would eventually type a work of Shakespeare.");
            Console.WriteLine("Let's see how well C# does...");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a word");
            Console.WriteLine("(3 letters or less is recommended)");
            string solution = userinput();

            int size = solution.Length;
            bool success = false;
            string guess = null;
            int correct;
            int best = 0;
            Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            while (!success)
            {
                guess = generate(size);
                correct = count(size, solution, guess);

                if (correct == size)
                {
                    success = true;
                }

                else if (correct > best)
                {
                    Console.Write("The best guess so far is: ");
                    Console.WriteLine(guess);
                    best = correct;
                }
            }

            watch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = watch.Elapsed;
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");
            Console.Write("It took " + ts.TotalSeconds + " seconds for the sharp C to type ");
            Console.WriteLine("\"" + guess + "\"");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Python:**

```
import random
import time
#This program generates a string of random letters and matches it with the user's string
#It does this until it's guess is the same as the user's string
#It also displays closest guess so far and time it took to guess


def generate():
    # generate random letter for each char of string
    for c in range(size):
        guess[c] = random.choice(alpha)


def count():
    # count how many letters match
    same = 0
    for c in range(size):
        if guess[c] == solution[c]:
            same += 1
    return same


print("They say if you lock a monkey in a room with a typewriter and enough time,")
print("the monkey would eventually type a poem by Shakespeare")
print("Let's see how well a python does...'")

user = ""
badinput = True
while badinput:
    # Make sure user only inputs letters
    user = input("Enter a word\n(5 letters or less is recommended)\n")
    if user.isalpha():
        badinput = False

solution = list(user.lower())
size = len(solution)
guess = [""] * size
alpha = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
random.seed()
success = False
best = 0    # largest number of correct letters so far
start = time.time()    # start timer

while not success:
    # if number of correct letters = length of word
    generate()
    correct = count()
    if correct == size:
        success = True
    elif correct > best:
        print("The best guess so far is: ", end="")
        print("".join(guess))
        best = correct

finish = time.time()    # stop timer
speed = finish - start

print("Success!")
print("It took " + str(speed) + " seconds for the python to type ", end="")
print("\"" + "".join(guess) + "\"")
input()
```

Comment: I guess I had better get back to typing up some Macbeth!

Comment: You may find this question on StackOverflow useful as well as it discusses pros and cons of instantiating a StringBuilder object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550702/at-what-point-does-using-a-stringbuilder-become-insignificant-or-an-overhead

Comment: **Use a profiler to answer a performance question**. Anything else is guessing.

Comment: @EricLippert, sage advice, certainly -- but in this particular case would profiling actually help?  He'd see that all the time is spent in generate() and count() and that neither is unusually slow -- but that is not illuminating, it's precisely what we would expect to see if it was operating properly.  Without understanding the consequences of repeated Random creation, the specific logical reason for why the program is so slow is elusive.

Comment: @agentnega: You see what you're doing there, right? **You are guessing**. Your guesses are good, educated guesses that are probably right, but they are still guesses. For all we know the reason that the C# program is slow is because there's something wrong with the `Console.WriteLine` causing the output to block or some such thing. I have profiled a lot of C# programs in my day and very frequently -- well over 10% of the time -- my initial guess about the cause of a slowdown is utterly wrong. Engineers solve problems by reasoning about *facts*, not *guesses*.

Comment: You say "I wrote it on C#, because it's compiled"; Python is also normally compiled.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know [python](/questions/tagged/python) so I'll focus on the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) code.

- Your program is coded upside down. One would expect `void Main` at the top, with the more specialized code below.
- Method names in C# are expected to consistently follow *PascalCasing* convention. Only your `Main` method does that, and if you were to adopt a *camelCasing* convention, `userinput` would be better off called `userInput`.
- It doesn't feel right that the `Count` method doesn't infer the number of iterations from the length of the string(s) it's given, and doesn't do anything to verify whether the index is legal, which at first glance seems like asking for an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Performance-wise, I think you'll need to factor out the randomness from your tests for any benchmarking to mean anything.

Using `StringBuilder` was a good call.

Comment: It is random, but if you run them both, the python is consistently much faster than the C#. Thanks for the tips. I put the methods at the bottom and changed the names.

Comment: Same if you take the creation of the `rnd` and `sb` objects outside the loop as @vals as pointed out? I suspect a seeding issue with all the instances of `Random` you're creating. Possibly you run the program 10K times and it runs 10K times with the same "random" sequence. Also C# is Jit-compiled from IL code, so yeah it's compiled, but to an *intermediate language* - there's the CLR doing its job, too. Not sure how fair your comparison is.

Comment: YES! the random initializing inside the method was the problem. Thanks, for pointing that out. Stepping through it in the debugger wasn't catching it. And yes, I know about C# and the way it compiles.

Comment: @user2180125 in all fairness, it's really vals' answer that caught the performance issue. If you're accepting my answer for the code review, I'll take it; but if you're accepting my answer for the advice about taking instantiation out of the loop, vals' answer should have the checkmark ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Never mind, I should have written a more thorough answer :-)

Comment: By the way, I am unsure about C#, were the objects ever deleted in the original code ?

Comment: @vals they'd be eligible for garbage-collection as soon as they're out of scope.

Comment: @user2180125, see [Jon Skeet's explanation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) about why/how the repeated creation of a Random object results in getting the same stream of (not-)random numbers.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I didn't check vals answer because he said to take the Random out just for a general performance boost. You found a specific error in the code that taking it out fixed.

Comment: @bobpal that's utterly cool, one more upvote on vals' answer and he gets [one of the sites' rarest gold badges](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/populist)!

Answer (score 50):

If you want performance, don't create objects in the inner loop:

```
    static string generate(int len)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();                    // creating a new object
        string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int letterInt;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();      // creating a new object
        ....

    }
```

create them once and reuse them

Comment: Ugh. How did I miss that! Good catch!

Comment: The objects are created once every user input, hardly a performance issue...

Comment: @UriAgassi they're not. Objects are created at each iteration of the while loop, which runs after the user input.

Comment: @Mat'sMug you are right, missed that :-)

Comment: +1 (late, I know, I [ran out of ammo](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1515/23788) early today!), but despite the upvotes, this is pretty much a *SO-Style* answer; on CR we prefer answers that *review* the OP's code - not necessarily long answers redacted in 2 hours, but while addressing OP's performance concerns (for example), consider commenting on *any aspect of the code*, including naming, formatting, best practices, etc. That said, welcome to soon-to-be-500 milestone!

Comment: I disagree with the conclusion. Object creation in a modern, OO, garbage collected, JITted language like C# or Java is so fast as to be one of the cheapest operations you can perform. Creating many ephemeral objects is already a generational GC's best case, and object pooling is almost always the wrong solution except for objects which are atypically expensive to create, such as Random. Don't object pool or reuse by default, only do it when there's actually an issue.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I somehow knew about the differences between OP and Code review, but I don't know C# enough to give advice about formatting and best practices. Anyway, highly surprised about my success !!!

Comment: @Phoshi I think that my use of the plural *reuse them* make you believe that I was suggesting using a pool of objects. My suggestion was much easier; just create one object of class Random and one of class StringBuilder, and them meant  the 2 objects.

Comment: @vals: It was more the general statement "don't create objects in the inner loop, create them once and reuse them" that made me think you were saying it as a rule rather than advice for this specific case. For this case specifically you are, of course, absolutely correct, and even without performance issues creating Randoms in a tight loop has potential issues with creating the same pseudorandom numbers!

Comment: @Phoshi I ran a profiler on the C# code. 82% of the time was spent in Random.ctor. So object creation here is not cheap because it dose much more than allocate the memory for the object.

Comment: @Andris: "Don't object pool or reuse by default, only do it when there's actually an issue". Random has *semantic* issues, never mind speed issues, and should never be created in a tight loop. This does not hold for the vast majority of objects, though.

Answer (score 20):

To answer the question of why your c# code is so slow.

It's this line. According to a profiler ~90% of the execution time is being taken up by recreating the Random object. You'll notice your python code only uses the random rather than recreates it.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

if you change the generate method to:

```
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    static string generate(int len)
    {
        //generates string of random letters, returns the random string
        string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int letterInt;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            letterInt = rnd.Next(26);
            sb.Append(alpha[letterInt]);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

These changes will show similar perf for both languages.

Answer (score 9):

In your python code you use a character array as your `guess`. In your C# code you build a `StringBuffer` instead. Try using a `char[]` instead.

Since you are on Code Review - I'll also give some thoughts about your code:

**Naming Conventions** - C# method naming is `PascalCase`, and python function naming in `snake_case`, so - `UserInput()` and `user_input():` respectively.

**Meaningful names** - `generate` and `count` do not convey well the meaning of the code in them `GenerateRandomString` and `CountSimilarLetters` is better. Same goes for `alpha`, `len`, `g`, `s`, etc.

Comment: You have `camelCase` and `PascalCase` confused, but at least you use them right. Though `camelCase` doesn't use underscores either - it just looks like a camel.

Comment: @Magus, fixed, thanks CamelCase can be used for both upper and lower first chars(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), and the pascal_case was a typo...

Answer (score 8):

I'd look at compiling your regex and having it as a class-level member for optimal reuse. Also lift the random number generator out the same way, as it's never good practice to continually regenerate it.

old code:

```
    static string userinput()
    {
        //Takes user input, makes sure it is all lowercase letters, returns string
        string input;

        while(true)
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[a-z]+$"))
            {
                return input;
            }
        }
    }

    private static string generate(int len)
    {
        // generates string of random letters, returns the random string
        Random rnd = new Random();
        string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int letterInt;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            letterInt = rnd.Next(26);
            sb.Append(alpha[letterInt]);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

new code:

```
    private static readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[a-z]+$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();

    static string userinput()
    {
        //Takes user input, makes sure it is all lowercase letters, returns string
        string input;

        while(true)
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (regex.IsMatch(input))
            {
                return input;
            }
        }
    }

    private static string generate(int len)
    {
        // generates string of random letters, returns the random string
        const string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int letterInt;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            letterInt = rnd.Next(26);
            sb.Append(alpha[letterInt]);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: If the strings are `123a56` and `123b56` then your count will be 3 and the OP's count will be 5.

Comment: @ChrisW dangit, it screws up the "best so far" display. Whoops. Correcting.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a late commentary on your Python program.

---

I know no C#. To be honest, though, I'm truly surprised that the C# isn't faster, because what you have written is *not* how to implement a fast variant in Python.

In Python, you'll want to use Numpy if things are getting slow. In fact, you'll want something like:

```
"""
This program generates a string of random letters and matches it with the user's string.
It does this until its guess is the same as the user's string.
It also displays closest guess so far and time it took to guess.
"""

import numpy
import time
from string import ascii_lowercase

# Everything is ASCII, which is what the "c" means.
letters = numpy.array(list(ascii_lowercase), dtype="c")

def brute_force(solution):
    """
    BRRUUUUTTTEEE FFOOORRRCCCEEEE!!!!

    Repeatedly guess at a solution until it matches.
    """

    # Convert to char array
    solution = numpy.array(list(solution.casefold()), dtype="c")

    best = 0
    while True:
        # Do loads of guesses (100000) at once
        guesses = numpy.random.choice(letters, (100000, len(solution)))

        # Check all of the characters for equality, and count the number
        # of correct for each row
        corrects = (guesses == solution).sum(axis=1)

        # Gets the highest-so-far at each point
        maximums = numpy.maximum.accumulate(corrects)

        # Gets how much the maximum increased
        changes = numpy.diff(maximums)

        # Indexes of the increases
        # numpy.where returns a tuple of one element, so unpack it
        [when_increased] = numpy.where(changes > 0)
        # Need to increase by one, because these are indexes into
        # the differences whilst we want indexes into the final array
        # for the *increased* (not increasing) elements
        when_increased += 1

        for index in when_increased:
            guess = guesses[index]
            correct = corrects[index]

            if correct > best:
                yield str(guess, encoding="ascii")
                best = correct

            if correct == len(solution):
                return


print("They say if you lock a monkey in a room with a typewriter and enough time,")
print("the monkey would eventually type a poem by Shakespeare")
print("Let's see how well a python does...'")

while True:
    print("Enter a word")
    print("(5 letters or less is recommended)")
    user_input = input()

    # Make sure user only inputs letters
    if user_input.isalpha():
        break

start = time.time()

for solution in brute_force(user_input):
    print("The best guess so far is: ", solution)

elapsed_time = time.time() - start

print("Success!")
print("It took ", elapsed_time, " seconds for the python to type ", repr(solution))
```

It might look more intimidating but there are only ~30 lines of logic there, most of which are trivial.

The basic idea is to make loads of random choices in bulk:

```
guesses = numpy.random.choice(letters, (100000, len(solution)))
```

which is fast. This makes a 100000xN matrix, eg. for N=3:

```
h s l
w t x
a m e
i x t
  ⋮
```

Then you can calculate the number correct for each row by comparing each row to the solution (`guesses == solution`) giving a `bool` array, and you can sum each row (`.sum(axis=1)`) to get the number correct.

The extra parts from there (`numpy.diff`) serve to *pretend* we did this sequentially, although we did not. It's not relevant in most real-world circumstances, where one can just print the best answer from that bunch.

Overall this is much faster than the original (>10x), and most of the time is spent in `numpy.random.choice`, implying it's not possible to meaningfully speed up further without replacing the high-quality random numbers that Numpy generates.

So don't go thinking that Python is slow because it's interpreted and dynamic. It's perfectly possible to have a high-quality implementation run fast with these kinds of programs.

---

Since this is Code Review, I'll also point out some things that you should be improving on:

- **Docstrings**, not *comments*.

  Write

  ```
  """
  This program generates a string of random letters and matches it with the user's string.
  It does this until its guess is the same as the user's string.
  It also displays closest guess so far and time it took to guess.
  """
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  # This program generates a string of random letters and matches it with the user's string.
  # It does this until its guess is the same as the user's string.
  # It also displays closest guess so far and time it took to guess.
  ```

  This might sound meaninglessly fussy, but it helps introspection.
- Reduce your usage of globals. Functions should (almost) *never* share state; it should be passed between them. Trust me on this. It means that you can reuse them and move them around without worrying about dependencies, for one. It also allows local changes to stay local.
- Try and clump IO in one place. If you look at my variant, all the printing is localized and the logic is separated. This modularizes the program, so you can move things around and mess with logic without having "things" in your way all of the time.
- `random.seed()` with no value given is pointless here. It should only be used after `random.seed(some_value)` to *remove* the seed.
- This code:

  ```
  done = False
  while not done:
      if ...:
          done = True
  ```

  is much better written

  ```
  while True:
      if ...:
          break
  ```

  Some people disagree. *They are wrong.*
- Things like

  ```
  for c in range(size):
      guess[c] = random.choice(alpha)
  ```

  where you're visiting each item in turn, are much better written without indexes, like:

  ```
  guess[:] = [random.choice(alpha) for _ in range(size)]
  ```

  although this really should be

  ```
  def generate(size):
      """Generate random letter for each character of string."""
      return [random.choice(alpha) for _ in range(size)]
  ```

  if you use my prior advice.

  The same goes for `count`, which can be

  ```
  sum(g==s for g, s in zip(guess, solution))
  ```
- **Don't** meaninglessly preallocate values, like `guess = [""] * size`. It just hides bugs.

  If you ever find you need to do that, you're probably not following my advice about not using globals.